# Link the different sources with delay time specifically for each source

Tags: delay, anylogic

I have a system that starts with 3 sources which are small, medium, and large. I want to do it for 3 different types of sources, combining and passing through a delay block. The delay block will be linked with a database reference which is a table consists of 2 columns (source, delay time). Thus, when the source passes through the delay block, it will automatically read the table and set the delay time for different types of sources.

I had seen the description in the AnyLogic Help and follow the instructions. The error is from the delay block which is the choice condition. I put source equals to agent.name but it keeps giving me an error which is name cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: that means that either name is not a variable that exists inside the agent, or that source doesn't exist, or both

Answer (score 0):

The source which produced an agent doesn't automatically get stored into the agent name. Plus, I think there isn't such as thing as `name` field in an `agent`. You can check out API [here](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/javadoc/com/anylogic/engine/Agent.html). What I think you could do:

1. In your agent create a property, let's call it `sourceName`
2. In **Source** `on at exit` action set the source name into the `agent.sourceName` property
3. Check the value of that property in your **Delay** block by checking value of `agent.sourceName`